# SQL Server - Log Shipping to Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, azure-vm

I'm looking for some advice regarding Log Shipping from SQL Server 2016 On-Premises to SQL Server 2016 on an Azure VM.

From my existing knowledge and research, there are a few ways of going about this.

**Option 1 - Hand-crafted Log Shipping**

Instead of using SQL Server's native log shipping, we do it manually i.e.

1. Write a script to Backup Log to a local file share
2. Write a script that copies the files up to the Azure storage account
3. Write a script to restore the files to the secondary database.

The main complication I can see with this is implementing a way for the restore script to know which files it needs to restore. We could track it in some way e.g. based on the last restored date.

**Option 2 - Use the native Log Shipping with a file share**

1. Create a file share on our network which is accessible from the secondary SQL Server in Azure
2. Configure Log Shipping to backup the T-Log to that folder
3. Configure Log Shipping to restore from that folder

This approach seems somewhat simpler, although step 1 above may be more complex than I realise at this stage.

I appreciate that these options are very high-level, but has anyone done this using the above approaches, or a different approach altogether?

Comment: You might consider using backup to URL to write the backups direct to azure blob. On the restore side I have a tool to do this that will hopefully be available soon. This is good to get you started with backup to url. https://gist.github.com/scheffler/7edd40f430235aab651fadcc7d191a89

Comment: Can you explain more about what the objective is? DR? Standby? Reporting?

Comment: The objective is purely DR. We want a copy of the databases to be in Azure and ready to go should the main data center suffer a catastrophic event.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm aware of backing up to URL but will check out that article nonetheless.   Ideally, I would like to keep a copy of the T-Logs on-premises, which is why I was considering the copy approach, rather than backing up directly to Azure storage.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this would be to use Ola Hallengren's solution to backup directly to Azure blob.  To get started with this I found **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/scheffler/7edd40f430235aab651fadcc7d191a89)** useful.

RESTORE FROM URL will also work if you need to restore your backups to your on-premise server.  This *might* eliminate the need for a local copy.  If you do need a local copy then you either need a process to push the files to Azure blob after backing up locally or a process to download them after backing up to Azure blob.

On the restore side, I created **[this tool](https://github.com/trimble-oss/sql-log-shipping-service)** that can be used to do **log shipping directly from Azure blob** which will help to simplify the setup.  The tool has been used internally for a while but has just been made public.  *(13th March 2024)*

Hope this helps

PS

Although you can log ship between SQL 2016 and 2019, be aware of the following issues:

- You won't be able to fail back.  Once your DB is online on SQL 2019, the only way to go back is to upgrade your on-premise instance to SQL 2019.  At least without scripting out your schema & data or bacpac.
- STANDBY option won't work.  Maybe not a big issue for DR.
- If the version and configuration don't match on the DR server this creates *some* additional risk in case of failover.  Ideally, consider planning an upgrade for the on-premise server if it hasn't already been considered.

Comment: That looks ideal! Thankyou David!! I note your comment about the version issue. I hadn't considered that but it's a great point.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the restore tool supports authentication via SAS but not the storage account key?

Comment: @FrugalShaun Yes.  In the portal if you navigate to the storage account and you can generate one from *Shared Access Signature* link.  The app uses this to enumerate the files in the blob container as this can't be done from SQL.  The SQL instance also needs to be configured to access the blob container.  That's described [here](https://gist.github.com/scheffler/7edd40f430235aab651fadcc7d191a89)

Comment: Thanks David. I've got it working with a SAS, which will need recycling based on the expiry date. The advantage of the storage account key is that it doesn't expire, but I guess it's less secure. 

One nice enhancement would be to allow for the deletion of old T-Log files based on a configurable value. I plan to do this with a PS script executed by a runbook that checks the file creation date. 

Fantastic tool!

Comment: @FrugalShaun That's great - glad it's working!  For deleting old logs I would look at using a lifecycle policy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: You can set quite long expiration dates on the SAS token if needed.

Comment: PS.  If you need monitoring for this, I also created [DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com/)

Comment: Thanks David. DBA Dash is on my to do list! I'll look at the lifecycle policy too! Thanks again.